# Como compartir datos de un componente a otro con props vuejs desde una api

Tags: vue.js

Quiero representar los datos de la api por un lado los nombres y en otro componente las características  como color de ojo. Para pasar los datos de un componente a otro. pero me da un error que dice que la propiedad personaje no esta definida. Property or method "personaje" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Componente padre:

```
 <Header :personaje="personaje"
    v-for="personaje in personajes"
    :key="personaje.id"/>
 <h1>{{personaje.name}}</h1>


export default {
   components: { Header },
   componets:{
     Header,
   },
data(){
   return{
      personajes:[],
}
```

Componente Hijo.

```
 <h1>Mi Header Principal  {{personaje}} </h1>


export default {
   props:{

     personaje:{
       type:Object,       
     }
```

Comment: es que personaje no esta definido.. esta definido dentro del for.. yo creo que querias hacer un div (para el for) y dentro del div, mandar el componente header y ahi si pasarle la propiedad personaje...

Comment: Si amigo al mandar el componente header  me sale perfecto, como puedo dar tu comentario como respuesta. soy nuevo por aquí gracias.

Comment: no podes, porque justamente es un comentario... Lo que podes haces, es mirar el [tour], mirar [ask] y si podes, responder vos mismo la pregunta (eso nos encanta) pero incluyendo el problema y como se soluciona... mira [answer].. de paso, luego, podes aceptar tu propia respuesta!!!

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado añadiendo mi componente debajo de la reiteración.

```
<div v-for="(personaje) in personajes" :key="personaje">  
     <Personaje :personaje="personaje"/>
```